# Hard disk not recognized at first boot?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, external-hard-drive, desktop

So my hard disk just died and I bought a new one. I didn't set it up myself, I let the guys from the computer shop do everything. So when I received my computer, they told me that there are also some problems with my motherboard for which I have to press `ctrl+del` at bootup to start the OS.
When I booted my PC at home it said that there's no bootable drive. So I restarted and it was all okay but everytime I start the PC it can't find my hard drive the first time.
Is there any way to fix this?

My motherboard is Gigabyte H81M-S2PV.

Comment: It doesn't see the drive from a cold boot, but sees it if you restart? Two things I'd check. (1) Look for BIOS updates (https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-H81M-S2PV-rev-10#support-dl-bios). (2) Look for drive firmware updates.

Comment: I’ve seen this some other times. One in particular was on superuser. Sounds like they didn’t really take long enough to solve the issue and fed you a story. I don’t believe this is an unsolvable problem. It may be a BIOS setting, or it may be some other device plugged in to your computer. Unplugging all other drives, and USB devices both internal and external is a good start. Try the BIOS update as suggested and try unplugging all the other devices if you feel confident enough. They might have even reinstalled the OS wrong somehow.

Comment: Well, I downloaded the latest BIOS which has a efiflash.exe file in it but whenever I run it it says windows can't find the file in the directory I just executed it from !!??!! 
And there's no firmware for my HD in official website, they don't even recognize the serial number of the drive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a power supply problem.
This is so sad, Alexa play despacito. :(

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, there can be two reasons for this:

1. The OS is not installed on the drive, thus it can not load it even though they told you it is installed, but from what you are facing here this is not your case

2. You need to tell the bootloader to load the hard drive.
In both cases you need to access the BIOS interface.
You can read about installing an OS from scratch and using BIOS [here](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1401617/how-to-clean-install-windows-10-and-create-boot-media/page/0/1) .


EDIT:

To set the default bootable drive, enter to your BIOS settings (instructions are usually written on the first screen you see) and go to Boot -> Boot Device Priority and set simply set your OS drive as the first option.

Comment: “You need to tell the bootloader to load the hard drive.”   This may be true, but how?   Please provide details (include a link if you’re copying from somewhere, but don’t post *just* a link).

Comment: Sure, I will update the answer 

Comment: I just installed fresh windows 10 a few hours ago and it's still the same. And I did set the hard drive as the first boot priority in BIOS.
When I boot for the first time I have Boot Priority #1 as disabled, but when I boot for the second time, it shows the #1 priority as the hard disk and boots just okay.

Comment: So in the first testcase it did not load the OS well, but now it does?

Comment: For some reason it won't find the HD in the first boot but boot properly on the second if I was fast enough. Turns out it was a power problem.
Thanks for trying to help.